# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'projectdb.rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent-relationship

i have a 3 tables rentals table,unit sizes tables and rental_units_pivot table.the rentals table contains the details of a rental,the unit sizes table contains a list of the units sizes such as i bedroom,2 bed room,etc.A rental facility might have more than one unit size.the unit sizes for each rental are saved in the pivot table.
am trying to get the count of each unit size in the rental facility.for example 3 1 bedroom units and 2 1 bedroom units for rental A.I have been able to get the unit sizes for each rental rental now i want to get the count for each unit size in a rental in the pivot table and display them in a datatable.here is what i have done

````
$active_rentals=Rental_house::with([
            'rentalunits' => function($q){
                $q->Join('rentalhouse_sizes','rental_houses.id','=','rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id');
                $q->select('title');
                $q->select([DB::raw("count(size_id) as total"), "size_id"]);
                $q->groupBy('rentalhouse_sizes.size_id');
        }])
        ->where('rental_houses.status','=',1)
        ->select('rental_houses.id','rental_houses.name','rental_houses.address','rental_houses.image','rental_houses.status')
        ->orderBy('rental_houses.name','Asc')
        ->get(); ```
````

here is my rentalhouse_sizes pivot table structure[image]

in the rental house model i have this relationship between the rentals and the unit sizes

```
 function rentalunits(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Rental_sizes::class,'rentalhouse_sizes','rental_id','size_id')->withPivot('status','amount');
}
```

i have tried joining the tables in a subquery but i get an error.
how can i be able to count the number of unit size for each rental house?

Answer (score 0):

When you do aggregations (i.e. `COUNT()`) you need to specify the groupings from your `SELECT` (including `JOIN`) case.

So you'd have to include `rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id` in your `groupBy` for your query to work correctly due to the aggregation.

Comment: i have edited the code to this  ```with([
                'rentalunits' => function($q){
                $q->Join('rentalhouse_sizes','rental_houses.id','=','rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id');
                $q->select('title');
                $q->select([DB::raw("count(rentalhouse_sizes.size_id) as total"), "rentalhouse_sizes.size_id"]);
                $q->groupBy('rentalhouse_sizes.size_id','rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id');
            }]) ```     then i get an error  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'rentalhouse_sizes'

Answer (score 0):

i solved by including all the pivot table columns in the groupby.

```
      ->with([
            'rentalunits' => function($q){
            $q->select("rental_sizes.title",DB::raw("count(rentalhouse_sizes.size_id) as total"), "rentalhouse_sizes.size_id");
            $q->groupBy('rentalhouse_sizes.size_id','rentalhouse_sizes.status','rentalhouse_sizes.amount','rental_sizes.title','rentalhouse_sizes.rental_id');
        }])
```